# Updating value from other table expensive on large data set

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table (table1) with 7 million rows and I need to copy one value from that table into a column from a different table (table2). I have tried to do this on a sample table with only 50 rows and it was very expensive (22 seconds). Am I missing something? It's a relatively simple operation and I can't have this take hours/days to run.

```
postgres=# explain analyze update table2 set myvalue=(SELECT myvalue from table1 t1 where table2.id=t1.id);
```

### QUERY PLAN

```
 Update on table2  (cost=0.00..14291311.70 rows=130 width=586) (actual time=22074.702..22074.702 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..14291311.70 rows=130 width=586) (actual time=407.754..22073.606 rows=50 loops=1)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Seq Scan on table1 t1  (cost=0.00..109933.08 rows=4836 width=32) (actual time=264.664..441.460 rows=1 loops=50)
                 Filter: (table2.id = (id)::text)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 737957
 Planning time: 0.110 ms
 Execution time: 22074.747 ms
```

Comment: Just a note that there is an index on table1.id value

Answer (score 1):

An UPDATE with a join, that is usually faster:

```
update table2 
  set myvalue = t1.myvalue
from table1 t1 
where table2.id=t1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating all the rows will be expensive.  However, for this query:

```
update table2
    set myvalue = (SELECT myvalue from table1 t1 where table2.id = t1.id);
```

You have a lot of scanning.  An index would help, specifically on `table1(id, myvalue)`.